# How to set the remaining estimate in Python Jira?

Tags: python, jira

Assume that i is set to an issue. All of the following (and a series of other pathetic attempts)

```
i.update(timeestimate=0)
i.update(timetracking_remainingestimate=0)
i.update(remainingEstimate=0)
```

fail with messages like

```
"Field 'timeestimate' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
```

Since Python Jira can be used to automate essentially everything I suppose there is a proper way to do this. Atm I resort to

```
jira.add_worklog(i, newEstimate=0, adjustEstimate='manual',
                 reduceBy=issue.fields.timeestimate, timeSpent='1m')
```

which has the very nasty side-effect of booking 1 minute on the issue. All hints are welcome. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Close! When updating issues, jira-python takes an [`update` parameter](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/1.0.10/jira/resources.py?#L445), "*a dict containing update operations to apply*". From my understanding you can pass anything the [JIRA API "Edit issue" route](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-editIssue) can take, which includes the work estimates of the time tracking.
In this case:

```
i.update(update={"timetracking": [{"edit": {"remainingEstimate": "2h"}}]})
```

`originalEstimate` is likewise editable.

Tested at the time of writing for version 1.0.10. It doesn't appear to be [documented](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#issues), sadly.